# Mysql - Examine last query run by thread in sleep state

Tags: mysql, connections

I am seeing some threads in the "sleep" state for longer than normal. Normal maybe being 1-3 seconds with the abnormal being up to 60 seconds or longer. It makes sense that this is an application issue so my question is if it's possible to see the last query run by a thread that is in a sleep state. From there I can hopefully track down the code that is leaving these connections open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to set general logs of mysql by add lines in /etc/mysql/my.cnf 's mysqld section.

```
general_log     = 1
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
```

Restart mysql -

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

If you don't want to restart mysql server-

```
SET global log_output = 'FILE';
SET global general_log_file='/var/log/mysql/mysql.log';
SET global general_log = 1;
```

If you wants to read logs from table, mysql database have a general_log table which insert all logs. you can get by-

```
   SET global log_output = 'table';
   SET global general_log = 1;
   SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log;
```

and you can disable by -

```
SET global general_log = 0;
```

Now you can see those process which are in sleep state & get its Id-

```
show full processlist;
```

open new tab and see the logs of ID & its running command-

```
cat /var/log/mysql/mysql.log | grep ID_value
```

or if you read logs from table then-

```
 SELECT * FROM mysql.general_log where thread_id=1;
```

Be careful to use it on Production server, it may effect your server performance (due to additional disk write) if transactions committing on huge no. per second.

Comment: Your answer is not suitable for a production workload. Enabling the general_log does not need a server reboot it's a dynamic variable. Be careful with enabling general log on a heavy loaded instance, it can generates lot of I/Os and slow down your platform.

Comment: yeah i know this, but it was only for temporary to find where the problem is :) not permanent

Comment: Yes but even temporary, you can overload your production. Depends on how your load and your configuration (mostly disks conf), if you are doing 20K ops and your /var/log/mysql uses the same disks than /var/lib/mysql it will be a mess in a second. In contrast, for a dev/qal environment I recommend to enable general_log by default, just say that, we must be precise on our answer to not be responsible for issues on stackexchange user databases :)

Comment: What if I were to output to a table? My thought is to keep a close eye on it and truncate it every 30 mins or so until I capture the scenario I need and then turn off logging. Our normal active thread count is 10-20/s it looks like.

Comment: @gwgeller You can get the query from the general log with little efforts by using bash/shell script & run into mysql.  :)

Comment: @MaximeFOUILLEUL would using a table have less of a performance impact? I am concerned about running this against our production DB.

Comment: @gwgeller I have edited my post, now you can use table which store all logs with time in mysql.general_log table.

Comment: @gwgeller nope general logging in table is worse than file. You can find some technical benches on the web (http://www.fromdual.com/general_query_log_vs_mysql_performance).